# Lua tables and iterating

Tags: lua, iteration, lua-table

Does this look right?

```
local data = {}

for i = 1, 22 do
  table.insert( data, data[i].title = "A title here")
end
```

I get a syntax error in the insert(), and I'm not sure what's causing it.
I'm guessing data[i].title isn't correct.

Comment: What do you want the table to look like after you insert the data into it? It looks like you're trying to assign "A title here" to a property of an object that already exists in the table... but there's nothing in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
local data = {}

for i = 1, 22 do
  local newdata = {
    title = "A title here"
  }
  table.insert(data, newdata)
end
```

`data[i]` will be `nil` until you create a new table and assign it there. Also, it looks like you're either trying to insert  the title into `data` or trying to insert a new table into `data`, it's hard to tell which. My example is assuming you're trying to make a new table, assign a title to it, and put that new table in `data`.

Comment: that's what I needed to get clarified.  thank you! And yes, I was trying to insert the title into data.

Answer (score 3):

Why use `table.insert` at all when this is so much clearer?

```
for i = 1, 22 do
   data[i]= {title = "A title here"}
end
```